# Validating React route with axios async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, axios

So I am creating a web app with server (node+express) and client (cra) sides.
I have an issue with validating user according to the jwt token I set as a cookie. The validation api endpoint on server side works as it should (tested it with postman) but the problem is the async check function that returns the promise therefore the route doesn't really know is it validated since the response is pending.

Here is the api endpoint on server side:
/api/token.js

```
router.get('/',
    jwt({secret:'token-secret' }),
    function (req,res) {
        console.log(req);
        if(!req.user) return res.sendStatus(401);
        res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    )
```

and here is the app.js on the client side: src/app.js that handles routing ( /dashboard should be available only for validated users)

```
function App() {

    function checkToken() {
        let token = Cookies.get('Access Token')
        axios.get('http://localhost:9000/api/token', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(res => {
            return res.status;
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    const handleToken = async () => {
        const result = await checkToken();
        return result;
    }

  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Route exact={true} path='/' render={() => (
              <div className="App">
                  <Home />
              </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path='/dashboard' render={() => (
              <div className="App">
                  {console.log('checktoken log', handleToken())}
                  {checkToken() ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />}
              </div>
              )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path='/login' render={() => (
              <div className="App">
                  <Login />
              </div>
          )}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

At this point I am aware that perhaps I shouldn't be doing a validation in this way since there is probably no way I can get the return before the render, perhaps it should be done in a lifecycle hook componentWillMount but I haven't been able to introduce it to this file (or everything should be done in an entirely different file).

Thanks

p.s. I've omitted all imports and export defaults since that is not relevant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've made it with a couple of substantial changes. First, in order to use history.push I had to refactor BrowserRouter part so now it looks like this
app.js

```
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard'  component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

Then I've decided not to use api/token.js. Instead of this api endpoint I've created a Higher Order Component that will check for cookies that have been set during login. Part that gave me most trouble is asynchronous nature of fetching cookies. That was solved with setTimeout inside getCookie function, I've called this function in componentDidMount lifecycle.

src/components/withAuth.js

```
state = {
            data: false,
            open: false,
            auth: false
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.getCookie();
        }

        getCookie(){
            this.setState({
                open: true,
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                const cookie = Cookies.get('Access Token')
                if(cookie) {
                    this.setState({
                        data: true,
                        open: false,
                        auth: true
                    })
                } else if (cookie === undefined) {
                    this.setState({
                        auth: true,
                        open: false
                    })
                }
            }, 700)
        }
```

In the end, in order to protect the route I've wrapped the component with HOC
src/Views/Dashboard.js

```
import requireAuthentication from '../components/withAuth';

class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DashboardContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default requireAuthentication(Dashboard);
```